# WMI class MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus on M.2 drives

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmi-query

I have a PowerShell script that runs on all workstations that looks at the WMI class `MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus` to look at the `PredictFailure` and if the results equal `true`, then we get alerted that the HD needs replaced.

Code:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\wmi –Class MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus).PredictFailure
```

I have read that new M.2 SSDs utilize SMART, but this WMI class is present on the machine, it is not populated with any data.  One instance of this would make me think it's me, but I have many M.2s in my environment and they are all blank.

Is there a different WMI class that I can get this data?

Comment: Is `.Active` property evaluated to ˙True˙? Check also `.Active` property  in  `MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictFunction` class.

Comment: I can confirm I see the same issue.
@JosefZ MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictFunction is also empty.

Comment: Check `(Get-WmiObject -Class "MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData" -Namespace "ROOT\WMI").SmartCapability`.  Possible Bit Values: **Bit 0** - power mode SMART data saving capability bit. **Bit 1** - SMART data autosave after event capability bit.